# Converting dataframe into time series

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I'm new to python and pandas and looking for the most efficient way to turn a dataframe like this:

| node_id | unit | start_dt | 00:00:00 | 00:15:00 | 00:30:00 | 00:45:00 | 01:00:00 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 50024 | temp | 2021-02-28 05:30:00 | 22.2 | 21.7 | 22.5 | 22.4 | 22.3 |
| 50024 | volt | 2021-02-28 05:30:00 | 122.2 | 122.8 | 123.5 | 124.1 | 122.6 |
| 51849 | temp | 2021-02-28 05:30:00 | 14.1 | 14.3 | 14.5 | 14.3 | 14.2 |
| 51849 | volt | 2021-02-28 05:30:00 | 124.1 | 124.5 | 125.1 | 123.9 | 125.2 |

Into something like this:

| time | node_id | unit | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-02-28 05:30:00 | 50024 | temp | 22.2 |
| 2021-02-28 05:45:00 | 50024 | temp | 21.7 |
| 2021-02-28 06:00:00 | 50024 | temp | 22.5 |
| 2021-02-28 06:15:00 | 50024 | temp | 22.4 |
| 2021-02-28 06:30:00 | 50024 | temp | 22.3 |
| 2021-02-28 05:30:00 | 50024 | volt | 122.2 |
| 2021-02-28 05:45:00 | 50024 | volt | 122.8 |
| 2021-02-28 06:00:00 | 50024 | volt | 123.5 |
| 2021-02-28 06:15:00 | 50024 | volt | 124.1 |
| 2021-02-28 06:30:00 | 50024 | volt | 122.6 |
| 2021-02-28 05:30:00 | 51849 | temp | 14.1 |
| 2021-02-28 05:45:00 | 51849 | temp | 14.3 |
| 2021-02-28 06:00:00 | 51849 | temp | 14.5 |
| 2021-02-28 06:15:00 | 51849 | temp | 14.3 |
| 2021-02-28 06:30:00 | 51849 | temp | 14.2 |
| 2021-02-28 06:30:00 | 51849 | volt | 124.1 |
| 2021-02-28 06:30:00 | 51849 | volt | 124.5 |
| 2021-02-28 06:30:00 | 51849 | volt | 125.1 |
| 2021-02-28 06:30:00 | 51849 | volt | 123.9 |
| 2021-02-28 06:30:00 | 51849 | volt | 125.2 |

Ultimately, I would like to take the resulting dataframe and load it into a database like TimescaleDB to learn more about that. Any help / guidance on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and then add timedeltas created by [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html) to datetimes with [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) for use and then drop column `level_3`:

```
df = df.set_index(['start_dt','node_id','unit']).stack().reset_index(name='value')

df['start_dt'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start_dt']) + pd.to_timedelta(df.pop('level_3'))
print (df)
              start_dt  node_id  unit  value
0  2021-02-28 05:30:00    50024  temp   22.2
1  2021-02-28 05:45:00    50024  temp   21.7
2  2021-02-28 06:00:00    50024  temp   22.5
3  2021-02-28 06:15:00    50024  temp   22.4
4  2021-02-28 06:30:00    50024  temp   22.3
5  2021-02-28 05:30:00    50024  volt  122.2
6  2021-02-28 05:45:00    50024  volt  122.8
7  2021-02-28 06:00:00    50024  volt  123.5
8  2021-02-28 06:15:00    50024  volt  124.1
9  2021-02-28 06:30:00    50024  volt  122.6
10 2021-02-28 05:30:00    51849  temp   14.1
11 2021-02-28 05:45:00    51849  temp   14.3
12 2021-02-28 06:00:00    51849  temp   14.5
13 2021-02-28 06:15:00    51849  temp   14.3
14 2021-02-28 06:30:00    51849  temp   14.2
15 2021-02-28 05:30:00    51849  volt  124.1
16 2021-02-28 05:45:00    51849  volt  124.5
17 2021-02-28 06:00:00    51849  volt  125.1
18 2021-02-28 06:15:00    51849  volt  123.9
19 2021-02-28 06:30:00    51849  volt  125.2
```

Or use [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) alternative:

```
df = df.melt(['start_dt','node_id','unit'])

df['start_dt'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start_dt']) + pd.to_timedelta(df.pop('variable'))
print (df)
              start_dt  node_id  unit  value
0  2021-02-28 05:30:00    50024  temp   22.2
1  2021-02-28 05:30:00    50024  volt  122.2
2  2021-02-28 05:30:00    51849  temp   14.1
3  2021-02-28 05:30:00    51849  volt  124.1
4  2021-02-28 05:45:00    50024  temp   21.7
5  2021-02-28 05:45:00    50024  volt  122.8
6  2021-02-28 05:45:00    51849  temp   14.3
7  2021-02-28 05:45:00    51849  volt  124.5
8  2021-02-28 06:00:00    50024  temp   22.5
9  2021-02-28 06:00:00    50024  volt  123.5
10 2021-02-28 06:00:00    51849  temp   14.5
11 2021-02-28 06:00:00    51849  volt  125.1
12 2021-02-28 06:15:00    50024  temp   22.4
13 2021-02-28 06:15:00    50024  volt  124.1
14 2021-02-28 06:15:00    51849  temp   14.3
15 2021-02-28 06:15:00    51849  volt  123.9
16 2021-02-28 06:30:00    50024  temp   22.3
17 2021-02-28 06:30:00    50024  volt  122.6
18 2021-02-28 06:30:00    51849  temp   14.2
19 2021-02-28 06:30:00    51849  volt  125.2
```